# Javascript compare value in object

Tags: javascript

The deepEqual function is supposed to take in 2 values in see if they are exactly the same. The results for the first and second test come back as expected. Is there perhaps something wrong with the way I'm incorporating the recursive call?

```
function deepEqual(obj1, obj2) {
  if (typeof obj1 == 'object' && typeof obj1 !== null && typeof obj2 == 'object' && typeof obj2 !== null) {
    if (obj1.length != obj2.length) {return false;}
    for (var prop in obj1) {
      if (typeof obj1[prop] == 'object') {deepEqual(obj1[prop], obj2[prop]);}
      if (obj1[prop] != obj2[prop]) {return false;}
    }
    return true;
  } else if (obj1 === obj2) {return true;}
  else {return false;}
}

var obj = {here: {is: "an"}, object: 2};
console.log(deepEqual(obj, obj));
// → true -> true
console.log(deepEqual(obj, {here: 1, object: 2}));
// → false -> false
console.log(deepEqual(obj, {here: {is: "an"}, object: 2}));
// → true -> false
```

Comment: @SPlatten It doesn't work for objects. It just tests for reference equality.

Comment: @SPlatten: The OP is clearly trying to test for equivalence, not identity.

Comment: You should test for the existance of 'prop' in obj2 before passing it onto deepEqual.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there perhaps something wrong with the way I'm incorporating the recursive call?

Yes, you're throwing away its return value. You should be checking its return value and, if it's false, returning `false` early.

```
if (typeof obj1[prop] == 'object') {
    if (!deepEqual(obj1[prop], obj2[prop])) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

---

Side note: There are several other issues in that code. I'm not going to get into a full review of it, but for instance, the `if` following the line above testing `obj1[prop]` to see if it's an object really should be `else if`, e.g.:

```
if (typeof obj1[prop] == 'object') {
    if (!deepEqual(obj1[prop], obj2[prop])) {
        return false;
    }
} else if (obj1[prop] != obj2[prop]) {
//^^^^------------------------------------------ here
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Unbelievable how fast you were on this :) Nice!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder So the original code wouldn't be able to return anything from that if statement. However, wouldn't the function still be able to finish the `for` loop and eventually return true? I was also under the impression that successive `if` statements were just run in order. Was it just repetitive in this case?

Comment: @James: The issue with the missing `else` is that if `obj1[prop]` and `obj2[prop]` are objects and they're not the **same** object, after doing the `deepEquals` call, you'll move on to the `if (obj1[prop] != obj2[prop])` check, which would be true (because they're different objects) and you'd return `false`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'm slightly confused. If the two objects after doing `deepEquals` are not the same, isn't it correct for the program to return `false`?

Comment: @James: I'm assuming the goal of `deepEquals` is to check for *equivalence*. E.g., `var a = {foo:"bar"}; var b = {foo:"bar"}; console.log(deepEquals(a, b)); // true` That's not what `==` and `===` with object references check; they check for *identity* (are the references both to the *same* object), not for equivalence (are the two different objects equivalent to each other, e.g., do they have the same properties with the same values).